# Different string resources for different flavor build types

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say I have one string I would like to change depending on my build type and flavor. What would be the best way to accomplish that?

I've created the following folder structure:

```
app/src/main/
app/src/flavor1/
app/src/flavor2/

app/src/main/res/values/my_strings.xml
app/src/flavor1/res/values/my_strings.xml
app/src/flavor2/res/values/my_strings.xml
```

This all works when I just want different string for each flavor. Now I would also like to separate those string by build type so I've done something like this:

```
app/src/main/
app/src/flavor1/
app/src/flavor2/
app/src/flavor1Release/
app/src/flavor2Release/
```

The problem which appears now is that if I want to create `values` folder inside `app/src/flavor1Release/res`, I receive the message that `values` folder already exists. How can I go around this issue?

Comment: did you check your actual file system whether it exists?

Answer (score 3):

You must do something like this :

```
app/src/main/
app/src/flavor1Debug/
app/src/flavor2Debug/
app/src/flavor1Release/
app/src/flavor2Release/
```

Comment: What if you want to separate the strings by build type but not flavor? Would it be `app/src/debug` and `app/src/release` or something else?